# HTML5 is not drawing lines properly, but does draw rectangles

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, the lines I'm trying to draw aren't appearing. The output from the console.log statement are as follow:

(39,259) (0,375) 
(39,-157) (0,-249)
(39,-233) (0,1458)
(0,-157) (39,718)
(0,1198) (39,1337)
(39,-84) (0,164)
(39,-140) (0,496)
(39,-157) (0,-249)
(39,-11) (0,378)
(39,-157) (0,378)
(39,-233) (0,1300)

By logging the ctxt, I have confirmed that is not an issue. The styling for the canvases are as follows:

```
width: 35px;
height:1879px;
left: 415px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 4.4%;
```

I've done a test with drawing a rectangle and that seemed to work.

```
for (var a = 0; a < arrows.length; a++) {
    var ctxt,
    ctxtX = 0,
    tgtX = 0;
    tgtGroup = groups[arrows[a].getAttribute('data-gID') - 1],
    categoryTxt = tgtGroup.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML,
    arrowCatTxt = arrows[a].parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML;

    if(categoryTxt == 'Engineering' && arrowCatTxt == 'Administration') {
        ctxt = canvases[0].getContext("2d");
        tgtX = canvases[0].offsetWidth;
    } else if(categoryTxt == 'Engineering' && arrowCatTxt == 'Fabrication') {
        ctxt = canvases[1].getContext("2d");
        tgtX = canvases[0].offsetWidth;
    } else if(categoryTxt == 'Administration' && arrowCatTxt == 'Engineering') {
        ctxt = canvases[0].getContext("2d");
        ctxtX = canvases[0].offsetWidth;
    } else {
        ctxt = canvases[1].getContext("2d");
        ctxtX = canvases[1].offsetWidth;
    }


    console.log('('+ctxtX +','+ (arrows[a].offsetTop - canvases[0].offsetTop) + ') (' + tgtX + ',' + (tgtGroup.offsetTop - canvases[0].offsetTop) + ')');

    ctxt.beginPath();
    ctxt.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctxt.lineWidth = 10;
    ctxt.moveTo(ctxtX, Math.abs(arrows[a].offsetTop - canvases[0].offsetTop));
    ctxt.lineTo(tgtX, Math.abs(tgtGroup.offsetTop - canvases[0].offsetTop));
    ctxt.stroke();
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you make a complete example on http://jsfiddle.net? I think your current example isn't quite enough code to diagnose your issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: No Javascript errors. And there's too many dependencies for a JSFiddle.

Comment: Actually, I can't imagine your thing drawing anywhere - 35 pixels wide? You never actually draw through it! I can't do the math at the moment but I'm pretty sure the slopes of your lines make them not intersect your canvas.

Comment: @ Rob G (39,259) (0,375) Let's take that first coord as our example. It should pass right through the entire width since it's 0 through 39. For height, the height of my box is far larger than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The canvas element requires width and height attributes directly, not only in the css: `<canvas id="thing" width="200px" height="200px">No support.</canvas>`
- Your canvas is a bit small, make it a lot bigger and try again.
- Also try removing your code, and draw just a single diagonal line from {10,10} to {width-10, height-10} and make sure that works first.

If you have multiple canvases, make sure the id's are different and that you're using different variables for the contexts. Also, inspect the elements and make sure they're not overlapping.

Good luck!

Comment: As per mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FCanvasRenderingContext2D#closePath()), all that does is "Tries to draw a straight line from the current point to the start."

Comment: Thank you for that, but unfortunately it is not the solution. Further explanation: There are two canvases which are selected, lines appear in one of them, but not the other even though I've confirmed the context for the first canvas is selected at some points through the loop.

Comment: @LeonardPauli Ok, downvote removed, but your suggestion for ClosePath is still wrong for this - that's only for closing polygons.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify some things. The canvases sit in between 3 columns. () | () | () The () are columns and | and canvases. The width, height, and position left are direct attributes, in order to refer to the elements in Javascript, I use getElementsByClassName and convert that to an array. One more note, I tried expanding the boxes and I can see that only the second column gets populated with lines (albeit incorrectly positioned lines).

Comment: I found my issue, I was setting the height and width in the style attribute rather than their standalone attributes. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be able to help :)